# Typescript - how to correctly type a member of abstract generic class based on possible extra implementations

Tags: typescript, inheritance, conditional-types

This is really hard to describe in words, but essentially I want to have a base abstract class that describes an abstract interface that needs to change depending on whether or not a derived class is implementing a certain interface or not.

Here's a TS playground showing the issue - everything is working fine, and the types are correct *outside* of the class, but internally typescript is reporting type errors.

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=53&pc=85#code/LAKAlgdgLgpgTgMwIYGMYAICySAOOYAmAPACoA06AqgHzoDeo66AtrgBQBuSANgFzokAlP0oBuUAF9QoKAE986ACLwwHGNhwA1HqQqbaAXgHoYAD1gQCAZyy58xTRUgJ4VWgH4q6fpvEhQSABGVlBwqFDoKNxIVjYA4jAQKihE+vTSIExBIWEoEQDmMFDKyACu3FDa3GzCSipqGlVEUAAWYFZ61H6MkQD2EDmleb1wbDhwqkiw6Fx86JqC9OhS-pnohZU8NfzKEw24Ta3tnelrTHBFpXAQ6EdWAHTtGvY16J5396w4bB+zi-y-Hh+JgrHpPOyEba3No2dq2PCEdCpChICCyWgMM7oC5QK43ADkX3x6Eg0PawOWGVBICiMRsu1UiLMFms6ASSQmKQgpWYgXgGJ6GxKSHKm2qtQZ+y0OjuFG5vP5pyY50u13QAAZROgAPTask2OQKKwtXrlAjoPl9OAXPLuHorakofohdAEeqIoxJADudT2kIAzIJQE6BhE3X6CFV0EZw4yCPcNlUalrdSToDBuNx2okrBhjb0vTZ5Xy4BQndaYHlg87etwYPduL18j95DBeghXe7IzwKLG1N3uIIU3ri-AKP7q6HOxHhaKozGuwmirOKkmhzq9ZBYJnswM8ybC+hR6WrTaoJOrLX643m4a2x2+4QV2Le13n1V16njxR1Rlg9FYl9ONniZcxElZdlkiIY9aDAZgcDrZhEigGwQOIb90BySB8gFVYmCFGAylXLYJXdRoZRhCgsIgHCllTO5blbTCTTNC0MHLM87SxHE8XQfF1XxClqSYL5OB4fhj0WTFlWxVUblme4oF6ABlUJsJqe0qQyEMXUfAg0OjI8YB9SVCDQthAz8HSwy7ND52nYCIXjRMSOHNNtyzXM92YgsbGo-IyxGM8LyvBsmxbfB2wc-s7J7aKzKcj83P8ih8X9fELxsiM0PfHhDL0tCl2KQiRWI8U3K3DNPJzfdfMwtSaMCisqxpGs6zC29WyigqnNy7hX2y3qSrnHhPz1FK+IEoA)

Answer (score 1):

[Polymorphic `this`](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#polymorphic-this-types) is not really helping you here; [there's no way to mark a class as `final` in TypeScript](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8306) the way you can in, say, Java... so it's always possible that polymorphic `this` has to refer to some narrowed type in some as-yet-unknown subclass.  For example:

```
class Foo extends Derived {
  map(val: number) {
    return "oops";
  }
}
new Foo(7).getDefaultVal().toUpperCase(); // error at runtime
```

Here we have, with no compiler errors, extended `Derived`.  But `Foo.getDefaultVal()` is just inheriting the implementation in `Derived`, whose return type is *supposed* to be `DeriveMapVal<this, number>`, where `this` is going to be `Foo` at the call site.  And `DeriveMapVal<Foo, number>` is `string`.  But `Foo`'s implementation is just returning a `number` and not a `string`, which is why you're getting the error: the compiler simply cannot verify that `number` is assignable to `DeriveMapVal<this, number`>.

---

As for how to deal with it, I guess it depends on what you want to do. The easiest solution I can think of is to narrow the subclass implementation to refer to the actual self-class and not `this`:

```
class Derived extends Generic<number> {
  getDefaultVal(): DeriveMapVal<Derived, number> {
    return 0; // okay
  }
}
```

This should work, although it's a bit strange that you can still subclass `Derived` as before, and the compiler *correctly* sees that `Foo` is not assignable to `Derived`:

```
class Foo extends Derived {
  map(val: number) {
    return "oops";
  }
}

new Foo(7).getDefaultVal().toUpperCase(); // error at compile time too, now
const d: Derived = new Foo(10); // error
const g: Generic<number> = new Foo(20); // error
```

I mean, `class Foo extends Derived` apparently does not guarantee that `Foo extends Derived` is true.  Weird stuff.  As long as you can handle that wrinkle then this might be a way for you to proceed.

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEB5A9jKSDeBYAUEkgJbAAuEATgGYLICyIMMEAJgDwAqANEgKoA+HASJEwTABQA3EABsAXEk4BKRXwDcIpAF8CWsgE8WSACJViUiIxgA1OV142hAXiVIIADwrBWWayw4bXlJqKn4hAH5+JEUbTXwtEAAjKDJKBDIkeFkQKCwAcQhgc3h2J2EEwlFk1PT4TIBzCDIzWgBXWTI7WQlVU3NLa272EGADRwF4rSJ4NGBatvq0SgkYSgsQCiQZBSQbZRwdPSqiJq65XsUzdcGmYbIAC2IoCYrRUUpmtspgJEfngB0z38bF6SCi-ygAPEMAkkIBOwOinhO3i710lXewKYAUufyeWGeSBBgV4owMQjwJw+Xx+SAA5DD6SRfpC0aIMVpOVVsrksNcLGx3F4ir4kIViutSsA2mAklRKdMkGdWiAOucen0BbdbPZIbwZXKFW93khPmRvr8AAzqJAAejt+KJhmMUAeaA6rCQ8qyy0+9QiSoxRG5MxyeSQADE0Ghhd4xdqhVT3jDpHJFIb5ZQDsnTebLUgAEQxzCF9khrlaYoAdyjMYkAHZlACVRB2p1ur0AWQ0HxmFQAMK5CC9W0O9yUSjLJCbM1tcjESDHGZzVJIVgDIWuGv9G6ggDMyi0s3mmQ3e9Y3SQrnPgtYLeaneUY8dpAoslkzyKUGQbrQ1awTMqF4WZJwgepj1XNBZAgAFZDQBo4SMCA0GoddN0vOReFvSxMNkZ97UdIDKF4fdINPdCL1VdUrxvDCHxaNs1Q7C4CPHN8IA-L95l-d0AKQYiQL9cCyHIqBoNg+DEJdFC0JwthqJY2RsIwxSNTYojZSzXgrWOY9w35DCSTjUUCiKEp2GIoRFxgGDIHIPwcTYSytOApBalIBpFUxURW3bDU8UTIY9QJXgPOALzDnHSE-mQ9z3U9b1kFA-0yEDakiHzOl6StelyyOHyxEkHYM1c7MTXeLLfh2bs0AAZTSTzeiDZcCrEs8jKcr1twgWtE1YEkJEPdkTzXeSBq62jKLvEkGKfF8WXfT8fx4+L-ywcKGiEsCIJ5KCYLghCkJYVDptwkluhUi8LrkDT3MaiLeHpfd6Xas62BJNSpvG2a-OYgK7o4riVp-Nb+M27bUrEiTDuk5DTp+rqvqw96Jv7VhkfwhaIYZXLjm5UBIFgOgo2IDwKi0DiaBJkkHHCCqkFTEqlD6DRKx8mTd0FYLZDp8pXE4EyfEc9GymCYBQkoemoj4GI9imKoajSDIsgM8VzKlMpvKVJW6kaZpMcCzceZGMYJgV95RrSRYexWNYNi2Zn9kOUNfMfVirmNu4QueV5c0q2lWQJIEoEGg4IWD1MUVuuXo9kfLXaIbF0bxGKiVpoIZzGbzTTNQOGSZFknSgBPWu0JBWt5CN+qFsUJQsqyGb+miPa5nVhn6g0ypzvN85tQikDQABrEADBaqpXarrBo1jTx40Mi8GaZ9MBLKnMlUy-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)

Comment: Hey @jcalz, thanks for the detailed answer - the 

> it's always possible that polymorphic this has to refer to some narrowed type in some as-yet-unknown subclass

phrase was the crux of what I was missing, thanks a lot. Unfortunately I think this means that I cannot quite achieve what I was going for as far as providing a simple way to modify the required implementation of an abstract method using an interface.

Comment: In my actual scenario, I'm in control of only the base class - this is distributed as a library that consumers implement themselves. The hope was that by providing an interface to implement that converts one datatype to another, I could change the required declaration elsewhere in that same class. This is currently implemented as a Remap extension class that they can choose to inherit from instead, but composition would be a more elegant DX

Comment: I'm going to leave this question open a bit longer, then mark your answer as correct if there is no other as-yet-unthought-of workaround. again, thanks!